# Image Circle Distortion in Processing / p5js

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, processing, p5.js

I am trying to implement a circle distortion function in Processing / p5js. Here are two examples of what I want to achieve:

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsSSDz and
http://jsfiddle.net/hto1s6fy

Both examples implement the same functionality - an original image is distorted into a 2d circle with an inner and outer radius.

I have been trying to translate the code from the jsfiddle example into my Processing / p5js sketch, but I have had limited success.

Here is my code and the resulting image:

```
let img;
let cx;
let cy;
let innerRadius;
let outerRadius;
let startX;
let startY;
let endX;
let endY;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('image.jpg');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
  image(img, 0, 0);

  noLoop();

  cx = width / 2;
  cy = height / 2;
  innerRadius = 0;
  outerRadius = 320;
  startX = 0;
  startY = 0;
  endX = img.width;
  endY = img.height;
}

function draw() {
  let angle = 0;
  let step = 1 * atan2(1, outerRadius);
  let limit = 2 * PI;
  
  push();
  translate(cx, cy);
  while (angle < limit) {
    push();
    rotate(angle);
    translate(innerRadius, 0);
    rotate(-PI / 2);
    let ratio = angle / limit;
    let x = startX + ratio * (endX - startX);
    image(img, x, startY, 1, (endY - startY), 0, 0, 1, (outerRadius - innerRadius));
    pop();
    angle += step;
  }
  pop();
}
```

Original image:
[image: Original image]

and result of code
[image: result of code]

Please is anyone able to tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with processing, but it seems like the people in your examples are using a different library than processing. So even though the function seem to be the same, it could be that there are small differences, which causes a different result.